# How to generate a random date and time between two dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, random-time-generation

Don't overlook the 'date AND TIME' part though.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
Time.at((date2.to_f - date1.to_f)*rand + date1.to_f)
```

You'll get a time object that is between two given datetimes.

Comment: This is a great solution however a note may be in order; you will need to convert your date to a time in order to call `to_f` on it. `Date` does not have a `to_f`.

i.e. `Date.today.to_time`

Comment: I need to find a way to give you another +1 - 2nd time this week I've referred to this answer!

Comment: For me, now at least, in 1.9.3, I can do `date1 + (date2 - date1) * rand`, and it comes out as a time.

Comment: Or even simpler: `rand((DateTime.now - 3.months)..DateTime.now)`

Answer (score 44):

You should be able to generate random date/times within a certain range.

```
now = Time.now
a_day_ago = now - 60 * 60 * 24

random_time = rand(a_day_ago..now)

# with activesupport required
up_to_a_year_ago = rand(1.year.ago..Time.now)
```

Your inputs need to be the `Time` class, or converted into one though.

You could do also do a range of time in epoch time and then use `Time#at`.

```
now = Time.now.to_i
minute_ago = (Time.now - 60).to_i
Time.at(rand(minute_ago..now))
```

Comment: In my opinion, this solution is much nicer than the currently accepted one by Evgeny.

Comment: One small remark, though: `1.year.ago` only works when you have *activesupport* loaded...

Comment: Good point @severin. I included code for support with and without activesupport loaded. Also added an example for epoch time ranges.

Answer (score 13):

Use the `rand()` method.

```
require 'time'
t1 = Time.parse("2015-11-16 14:40:34")
t2 = Time.parse("2015-11-20 16:20:23")
puts rand(t1..t2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `time.to_i()` (see class `Time`) to convert your dates to integer, randomize between those two values, then reconvert to time and date with `Time.at()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about ruby but why don't you just generate an integer and use it together with a timestamp? Then simply convert the timestamp to your desired format.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the midpoint and the offset range on either side of the midpoint you can use my ish gem: https://github.com/spilliton/ish

```
mid_date.ish(:offset => 60.days)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Time.at(rand(Time.parse('some date').to_i..Time.now.to_i))
```

Comment: Came to the same solution, the most readable option among other answers, IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way

`rand(DateTime.now..3.days.from_now.to_datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference in for example minutes between the two dates, generate a random number between 0 and that number, and add that number of minutes to the first date.